# Problema com Sockets

Tags: java, socket

Tenho um problema com sockets, eu queria que o meu servidor recepcione um valor e de seguida queria transformá-lo em uma `String`, de forma a depois incluir em condições `if`. No entanto, apesar do servidor recepcionar o texto sem problema, eu não consigo passar o valor para uma `String`.

Segue o código do servidor:

```java
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package javasockets;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class JavaSockets {

    public static String T = "s";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            ServerSocket sckServer = new ServerSocket(5000);

            System.out.println("Porta 5000 aberta!");
            Socket sck;

            while (true) {

                sck = sckServer.accept();
                try (Scanner entrada = new Scanner(sck.getInputStream())) {

                    while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {

                        System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());
                    }
                    String texto = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("ola" + texto);
                    String fnames = texto;
                    System.out.println("ola" + fnames);
                    System.out.println(texto);
                    if (texto.equals(T)) {
                        System.out.println("LOOL");
                    }
                }
                sckServer.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Segue o código do cliente:

```java
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package javasockets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            System.out.println("O cliente se conectou ao servidor!");

            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintStream saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

            while (teclado.hasNextLine()) {
                saida.println(teclado.nextLine());
            }
            saida.flush();
            saida.close();
            teclado.close();
        }

    }

    static Object getInetAddress() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou sem computador no momento (celular). Poderias formatar a parte de código? (Indentação, etc)

Comment: Quando tenta salvar como String aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não, simplesmente a String texto não tem valor nenhum guardado.

Answer (score 2):

Não está claro quando você diz que recebe o texto mas não o consegue passar para uma String. A recepção já é uma String.

Acredito que seu problema possar ser no seu servidor, neste ponto:

```
                while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {

                    System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());
                }
                String texto = entrada.nextLine();
```

Você está consumindo toda a entrada no `while` e apenas apresentado-a, e evidentemente o `while` irá acabar quando não houver mais algo a ser consumido (`hasNextLine()`), então após o `while` você simplesmente passa nada para `String texto`.

Tente assim:

```
                String texto = "";

                while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {
                    texto += entrada.nextLine() + "\n";
                }

                System.out.println(texto);
```

Você guarda todo o conteúdo antes em uma variável para depois mostrar. Observer a inclusão do escape de linha `\n`, isso faz o `ln` do `println`. Daí você pode fazer o que quiser com o `texto`.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, efetivamente o problema esta no while.. Coloquei o código todo dentro do while e resolveu...

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflowPT. Obrigado por ajudar a comunidade! +1 pela resposta.